Mirroring array elements in C++
I wonder if it is possible to "mirror" array elements. Suppose I have an array of integers of size 3 arr. I want arr[0] and arr[1] to share the same value. This means when I update with arr[0] = 3, I expect arr[1] to return 3. Likewise when I update with arr[1]=10, I expect arr[0] to return 10.
Here is one way I can emulate this behavior:
#include <iostream>

struct Array
{
    int a;
    int b;

    int& operator[](int index)
    {
        switch (index)
        {
        case 0: return a;
        case 1: return a;
        case 2: return b;
        }
    }

    const int& operator[](int index) const
    {
        switch (index)
        {
        case 0: return a;
        case 1: return a;
        case 2: return b;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    Array arr;
    arr[0] = 3;
    std::cout << arr[1] << std::endl;
    arr[1] = 10;
    std::cout << arr[0] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

Are there any better ways to do it?

You can certainly do that with pointers.  Doing it the way you have described is poor software engineering, because it violates the Principle of Least Astonishment -- no one would expect an array to behave that way.

@TimRoberts array of integer pointers?

Yes.  The syntax would be different (*arr[0] = 1), but that's good, because it points out that you're doing something unexpected.

I disagree with Tim Roberts’ conclusion. Doing it this way is fine, and a better solution than using pointers. The premise, however, is still bad (as Tim Roberts noted, violating POLA). An “array” does not behave this way. Find another name for this weird object. (Edit: I would also be inclined to use ( ) instead of [ ] for element acess too... but that’s my opinion.)

I agree that the class way is the way to go, just don't call it an array, because it is not one.  Not sure what to call it but call it something special that way people will have to look it up and make sure they know what they are using.

I suspect OP you really wants is a std::map or std::unordered_map to keep track of virtual indices to real indices in a collection.  Maybe a better question for OP is what are you really trying to do?

For context, I was trying to find a "nice" data structure to model general-purpose registers for ARM4 cpu. Some registers can differ depending on cpu operating mode.

@selbie That was also my idea but since the mapping is presumable know at compile time the overhead of map's might be a bit too expensive (if this code is for an emulator)

if I understand correctly you want mode dependent access to different indices some of which can map to the same register.
Will something like this work for you?
I think you can figure out what to do if you want to switch modes (e.g. using an enum and a setmode call)
#include <cassert>
#include <array>

class Registers
{
public:
    int& operator[](int index)
    {
        // use one extra level of inderiction to get mapped indices
        return registers[(*active_mode_indices)[index]];
    }

private:
    using mode_indices_t = std::array<int, 5>;

    // Here you will have mode dependent index mappings
    mode_indices_t mode1_indices = { 0, 1, 1, 2, 2 };
    mode_indices_t mode2_indices = { 0, 0, 1, 1, 2 };

    // set the active mapping
    mode_indices_t* active_mode_indices = &mode1_indices;
    std::array<int, 3> registers = { 0, 0, 0 };
};

int main()
{
    Registers registers;
    registers[1] = 1;
    assert(registers[2] == registers[1]);
}


Based on comments, this may be a good approach for you:
struct register_type { };

typedef uint64_t address_type;

typedef map<address_type, register_type*> register_file;

register_file registers;

// create a register and make it available at addresses 1 and 2
auto reg = new register_type;
registers[1] = reg;
registers[2] = reg;

Here, the same register object is now available under two addresses. Things to do next:

Fill in the register type's internals, like state and behaviour.
Perhaps wrap the register_file map in a class that dereferences the pointers stored in the map. Point is, you need to use *registers[1] to access the register currently, but you want registers[1] without the asterisk.
It's not fully clear how you intend to use this. Code I worked on, writte n in C though, used *(uint32_t*)(BASE_ADDR + REGISTER_OFFSET) = 0x12345678. If you want to write similar code that doesn't know whether it writes to an actual register or to a simulated one, you will have to support additional operators, perhaps even use accessor functions for reading and writing registers.
Optional but probably optimal would be to define a mapping at compile time. The available registers are already known, so it should be possible to catch any invalid accesses with that, too. This would provide the best performance, but also require the most amount of coding.

